# Creating Table combining from different variables

Tags: powershell-2.0

Below is the script i wrote to grab some user information from Active Directory and the group membership and also the mailbox availability for the accounts.

```
Import-Module Activedirectory
$ou = Read-Host "Please enter the OU Distinguished Name eg: OU=APAC,DC=kabwahib,DC=local"
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase $ou

foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $internet = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | where {$_.name -eq "G_internetaccess_full"} | select Name
    $vpn = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | where {$_.name -eq "G_RemoteAccessAllowed"} | select Name

if ($user.msExchRecipientTypeDetails -eq $null)

{
$mailbox = "False"
}
else
{
$mailbox = "True"
}

if ($internet -eq $null)
{
$internet = "False"
}
else
{
$internet = "True"
}

if ($vpn -eq $null)
{
$vpn = "False"

}
else 
{
$vpn = "True"
}

$report = New-Object PSObject
$report | Add-Member Noteproperty "User ID" $user.samaccountname
$report | Add-Member Noteproperty "DisplayName" $user.DisplayName
$report | Add-Member Noteproperty "Job Title" $user.Title
$report | Add-Member Noteproperty "Email" $mailbox
$report | Add-Member Noteproperty "VPN" $vpn
$report | Add-Member Noteproperty "Internet" $internet

$report | Format-Table | Out-File "C:\Scripts\ADquery\userlist.csv" -Append

}
```

The problem is now, the output I'm getting is not the way I wanted.

Current Output sample :

```
User ID       DisplayName   Job Title    Mailbox      VPN          Internet    
-------       -----------   ---------    -------      ---          --------    
Test2         Test2                      True         True         False       



User ID       DisplayName   Job Title    Mailbox      VPN          Internet    
-------       -----------   ---------    -------      ---          --------    
test10        Test10                     True         False        True        



User ID       DisplayName   Job Title    Mailbox      VPN          Internet    
-------       -----------   ---------    -------      ---          --------    
test11        Test11                     True         False        True        



User ID       DisplayName   Job Title    Mailbox      VPN          Internet    
-------       -----------   ---------    -------      ---          --------    
test12        Test12                     True         False        True
```

My Expected result :

```
User ID       DisplayName   Job Title    Mailbox      VPN          Internet    
-------       -----------   ---------    -------      ---          --------    
Test2         Test2                      True         True         False       
test10        Test10                     True         False        True        
test11        Test11                     True         False        True         
test12        Test12                     True         False        True         
test13        Test13                     True         False        True          
test14        Test14                     True         False        True
```

Can Anybody help me to check my script on how to eliminate repetitive headers and generate in a nice csv file as my expected result above ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Format-Table` from the export:

```
$report | Out-File "C:\Scripts\ADquery\userlist.csv" -Append
```

What's happening is that every time you call `Format-Table`, it generates a new table. Also, the table generated is formatted for console output, and will not translate to a .csv file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I have figured out how to make it happen. Below is my updated script.

Import-Module Activedirectory
$ou = Read-Host "Please enter the OU Distinguished Name eg: OU=APAC,DC=kabwahib,DC=local"
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase $ou

```
$colreports = @()
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $internet = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | where {$_.name -eq "G_internetaccess_full"} | select Name
    $vpn = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | where {$_.name -eq "G_RemoteAccessAllowed"} | select Name

if ($user.msExchRecipientTypeDetails -eq $null)

{
$mailbox = "False"
}
else
{
$mailbox = "True"
}

if ($internet -eq $null)
{
$internet = "False"
}
else
{
$internet = "True"
}

if ($vpn -eq $null)
{
$vpn = "False"

}
else 
{
$vpn = "True"
}

$report = New-Object PSObject
$report | Add-Member Noteproperty "User ID" $user.samaccountname
$report | Add-Member Noteproperty "DisplayName" $user.DisplayName
$report | Add-Member Noteproperty "Job Title" $user.Title
$report | Add-Member Noteproperty "Email" $mailbox
$report | Add-Member Noteproperty "VPN" $vpn
$report | Add-Member Noteproperty "Internet" $internet


$colreports += $report

#$report | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders| Out-File "C:\Scripts\ADquery\userlist.csv" -Append

}

$colreports | Export-Csv "C:\Scripts\ADquery\userlist.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "|"
```

I have added the line below to collect all the result into one variable and write it all in the csv in bulk.

```
 $colreports += $report
```